# how to use div display block in hover of other div id

Tags: css

how to open `div` tag on hover `href` tag

this is my code for display div tag on hover href tag

`#Services` is `id` of `href` tag

`#Services` is `id` of `div` tag

```
#Service:hover {
    #Services{display: block;}
}
```

Comment: First of all, `href` is an attribute which is used on `a` tag, so it's not a tag, and secondly, you cannot nest the CSS rules like that, have a `div` adjacent to `a` tag and write `#service + div {display: block;}` where I assume you have assigned an `id` of `#service` to `a` tag

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this

HTML

```
<a id="service">hover Me</a>
<div id="services">Hello I'm here.</div>
```

CSS

```
#services
{
    display:none;
}

#service:hover + #services
{
    display:block;
}
```

Here I am using sibling selector `(+)`. So make sure your elements matches with above html.If your html structure is not same as mine then don't worry there are other selector as well which you can use.

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5djqz/)**

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

**Css:**

```
#Service:hover #Services{
    display: block;
}
```

**Html:**

```
<a href="" id="Service">
     <div id="Services">With some text</div>
</a>
```

When you want `#Services` to be viseble with `display:block;`. By hovering over `#Service`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MBJqg/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the HTML markup is the following:

```
<div id="Service"></div>
<div id="Services">Content</div>
```

The CSS would be:

```
#Service:hover + #Services {
   display: block;
}
```