# How to display block on hover a tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

how to open `div` tag *on hover* `a` tag

this is my code for display div tag on hover a tag

`#Service` is `id` of `a` tag

`#Services` is `id` of `div` tag

and my condition is a tag is define inside `ul` , `li` tag and `div` tag is define outside of `ul` tag

```
<ul><li><a href="#" id="Service">Services</a></li></ul>

<div id="Services">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Services {
     display: none;
}

#Service:hover + #Services {
     display: block;
}
```

Comment: If am not mistaken, I am seeing this question for the second time, you posted it again right?

Comment: Aaaah yes, you are having some hard time doing this ya? 3 questions for the same thing, the way you are trying won't work, CSS cannot pop out of an element and select some other element, in your HTML, the elements aren't adjacent, so make them adjacent, or use JavaScript

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797095/how-to-use-div-display-block-in-hover-of-other-div-id?

Answer (score 1):

For the `+` CSS selector to work, you'll need `#Services` to be the direct sibling of `#Service`.

Since it's not the case here, you'll have to :

- Either **change your HTML markup** to fit this requirement
- Or **use Javascript** to get the desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

This will work - notice that the Services div is a sibling for a link:

```
<style type="text/css">
#Services{
  display: none;
}
#Service:hover + #Services {
     display: block;
}
</style>
<ul><li>
<a href="#" id="Service">Services</a>
  <div id="Services">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or javascript way using jquery - it will keep your html the same:

```
<style type="text/css">
#Services{
  display: none;
}
</style>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
  $("#Service").mouseover(function(){
    $("#Services").show();
  }).mouseout(function(){
  $("#Services").hide();
  });
});
</script>

<ul><li>
<a href="#" id="Service">Services</a>
</li></ul>
<div id="Services">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```